# PLS 00103 when running Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, plsql

When I compile, I get the errors like `PLS- 00103 "cur1" when expecting one of the following`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY SSS IS

   PROCEDURE sample1(obj_CustomerID IN varchar2,
                    obj_DelUserID  IN varchar2,
                    cur1           OUT T_CURSOR1,
                    cur2           OUT T_CURSOR2)IS


  BEGIN

   TEMP_CUR1 cur1%ROWTYPE;

   TEMP_CUR2 cur2%ROWTYPE;



    OPEN cur1 FOR
      select distinct cf.fleet_id, cf.fleet_name, cf.customer_id
        from customer_fleet cf, vehicle_register vr, asset_register ar
       where cf.customer_id = vr.customer_id
         and cf.fleet_id = vr.fleet_id
         and vr.vehicle_id = ar.vehicle_id
         and vr.customer_id = ar.customer_id
         and vr.is_active = 'Y'
         and cf.is_active = 'Y';
         FETCH cur1
      into temp_cur1;
    close cur1;

    OPEN CUR2 FOR
      select TEMP_CUR1.fleet_id,
             TEMP_CUR1.fleet_name,
             TEMP_CUR1.customer_id
        from cur1
       where customer_id = obj_CustomerID;

    FETCH CUR2
      INTO TEMP_CUR2;
    CLOSE CUR2;

end Sample1;

END SSS;
```

The error happens at lines

```
   TEMP_CUR1 cur1%ROWTYPE;    
   TEMP_CUR2 cur2%ROWTYPE;
```

Comment: Please include the exact error you're receiving in the body of the question. The title of the question is not for that.

Comment: also, avoid using chat-language.

Answer (score 1):

Declaration of variables has to happen between `IS` and `BEGIN`, not after `BEGIN`:

```
PROCEDURE sample1(obj_CustomerID IN varchar2, 
                    obj_DelUserID  IN varchar2, 
                    cur1           OUT T_CURSOR1, 
                    cur2           OUT T_CURSOR2)
IS 

   TEMP_CUR1 cur1%ROWTYPE; 
   TEMP_CUR2 cur2%ROWTYPE; 

BEGIN
```

Comment: Thanks.. But, now i getting the PLS-00320 error: the declaration of the type is malformed..

Comment: Does it help to replace `cur1%ROWTYPE` with `T_CURSOR1` and `cur2%ROWTYPE` with `T_CURSOR2`?

Comment: NO.. cur1%ROWTYPE replace with cur1 and and cur2%ROWTYPE replace with  cur2.. T_CURSOR1 and T_CURSOR is a REF CURSOR

Answer (score 0):

Using `Strongly typed REF CURSOR`.

```
PROCEDURE sample1(obj_CustomerID IN varchar2, 
                    obj_DelUserID  IN varchar2, 
                    cur1           OUT T_CURSOR1, 
                    cur2           OUT T_CURSOR2)
IS 
   TYPE curr1 IS REF CURSOR RETURN T_CURSOR1%ROWTYPE;
   TYPE curr2 IS REF CURSOR RETURN T_CURSOR2%ROWTYPE;

   TEMP_CUR1 curr1; 
   TEMP_CUR2 curr2; 

BEGIN
```

and then

```
 FETCH cur1
  INTO TEMP_CUR1
```

and

```
FETCH cur2
 INTO TEMP_CUR2
```